# Regex to parse command line options

Tags: java, regex, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm faced with a need for parsing a string into key-value pairs, where the value may be optional. Standard command line parsers are not useful, because all the ones I checked accept a `String[]` and not a `String`. Thus, I resorted to regex, and sure enough, faced with the following:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

First, the input string:

```
"/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/ruby /opt/sensu/embedded/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb " +
"--crit 25 --host 99.99.999.9999:8082 --period -5mins --target 'alias(scale(divideSeries(" +
"summarize(sumSeries(nonNegativeDerivative(transformNull(exclude(" +
"\\\"unknown\\\"), 0))), \\\"30d\\\", \\\"sum\\\", false),summarize(" +
...gigantuous string
\\\"sum\\\", false)), 100), \\\"3pp error rate\\\")' " +
"--unknown-ignore --warn 5"
```

Next, my regex:

```
(--(?<option>.+?)\s+(?<value>.+?(?=--))?)+?
```

the above *almost* works, but not quite.

Output:

```
--crit 25 
--host 99.99.999.9999:8082 
--period -5mins 
--target 'gigantuous string' 
--unknown-ignore 
--warn
```

Why is the value of `--warn` not picked up?

Comment: Why not just pass each parameter separately into `args[]`?

Comment: Your input is a shell command. How did you end up trying to write a shell parser in Java?

Comment: All I've is the string.

Comment: @thatotherguy, I can't speak for the poster, but I want to be sure the web API I'm unit testing is invoking a shell command properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're doing a positive lookahead to the next `--` at the end of the regex (`(?=--)`), the value of the last parameter in the string isn't picked up as it's not followed by `--`. Accepting the end of the string as an alternative (`(?:(?=--)|$)`) and then filtering values that don't start with `--` (by replacing `.+?` with `.(?:[^-].+?)?`) should behave in the way you want:

```
(--(?<option>.+?)\s+(?<value>.(?:[^-].+?)?(?:(?=--)|$))?)+?
```

(However, as others have mentioned, I'd be very surprised that there isn't a Java argument parsing library that would suit your use case. Even if it means writing the code to split your string into arguments yourself, it might be less brittle.)

Comment: Nop! it picks up `--unknown-ignore --warn 5` together.

Comment: Oh yes, so it does. What about adding `[^-]` at the start of the `value` group? (`(--(?<option>.+?)\s+(?<value>[^-].+?((?=--)|$))?)+?`)

Comment: No. I appreciate your time, but there are plenty of regex testers online, you should check first; this seems like throwing Spaghetti at the wall hoping it would stick.

Comment: Ah, sorry, looks like I misconfigured my tester. `(--(?<option>.+?)\s+(?<value>.([^-].+?)?((?=--)|$))?)+?` should work.

Comment: Some of the groups were not necessary, I converted them to non-capturing `(--(?<option>.+?)\s+(?<value>.(?:[^-].+?)?(?:(?=--)|$))?)+?`. Other than that, your answer works for me, so I accepted it. Thanks.